# AngularJS: $scope NOT updating view from second controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wonder if anyone can help?

I have 1 html file and a controller assigned via the $routeProvider like so

```
          .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/contents.html',
            controller: 'FirstCtrl'
```

Everything was working fine, I had my view do a ng-repeat over a object and the view updated like so

```
   <tbody ng-repeat="item in contents.data">
     <tr>
```

this code was working fine, I updated my item via the FirstCtrl like so

```
   $scope.contents = {};
   $scope.contents.data = {...}
```

I have extracted this functionality out into its own controller, its still the same view, so  i have 1 view and 2 controllers... The second controller is used by specifying ng-controller on the tbody like so

```
   <tbody ng-controller="SecondCtrl" ng-repeat="item in contents.data">
     <tr>
```

Now I know the controller is working as I have insert an ng-click on a  and it fires the the function. I am also updating my $scope from my second controller but it seems to be also blank..

From the documentation it states that if the $scope exists in the parent controller (first) then the child controller overwrites it (second) but this is not my case, I don't have it defined in the first controller any more.

I even tried a simple test of

```
    $scope.testme = "hi";
```

and the view

```
    {{ testme }}
```

and nothing ... Its like the $scope doesn't exist.

Does anyone know whats going on? I am using it correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This only happens on the second controller, the first controller works and I am able to update the $scope.

Comment: Post code of your first and second controllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are initializing the $scope.contents inside of the SecondCtrl then you are probably experimenting some $scope shadowing.

Try creating the "contents" object inside of the FirstCtrl and when you update the data. Do not recreate the contents object (i.e. Don´t do >> `$scope.contents = {};`) just update the data object/array >> `$scope.content.data = ...`

If this doesn´t solve your problem, can you please provide a working fiddle with your problem. You can use this one as a starting point http://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/ADukg/